# Running gulp using Symfony Process results in command not found

Tags: laravel, gulp, symfony

I am trying to run gulp using envoy from a controller on a Laravel installation using Symfony Process to no luck. I keep getting an error back reading "The command "envoy" failed. Exit Code: 127(Command not found)". I have attached the code I am using below:

```
$process = new Process('envoy', base_path() . '/vendor/laravel/envoy');
$process->setTimeout(60);
$process->setIdleTimeout(60);
$process->setWorkingDirectory(base_path());
$process->run();

$process->start();

$process->wait();

if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}
```

My question is, how come the command is being read as not found even though I am targeting it directly?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Any luck with this?  I'm having the same issue.  I get that error every time I try to execute a command in /usr/local/bin.

Also, new Process("echo \$PATH")->run()->getOutput(); has /usr/local/bin included.

Comment: I'm in the same situation, any updates?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change this line like so:

```
$process = new Process('envoy vendor/laravel/envoy');
```

can you try it? Not certain it work, but I think it's something like that. Since you are using base_path(), I think it's pointing to a different directory than you expect.